# Range(5) is returning 4 or 5 random integers

Tags: python

I've created a program to generate 5 random integers from 1-10 and add them to an empty set. For some reason, when I run the program, it will sometimes return 4 integers, and other times 5. What is happening here?

```
import random
set1 = set()

for x in range(5):
    integer = random.randint(1,10)
    set1.add(integer)

print(set1)
```

Comment: Do a little experiment: add the number `1` three times to a set and observe the result.

Comment: @KButler, first, review the previous two commends, keep in mind that by definition a set cannot contain duplicated elements. Second, do you need to generate 5 unique elements?

Comment: hmm. I see. Yes, i have run it many times now and see that it can return 2 or 3 numbers as well. Thank you for the feedback all.

Comment: @KButler Consider accepting one of the answers if they helped.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a set, sets can't contain duplicates, if the same number is generated twice it will only occur in the set once, theoretically its possible your output would only have 1 number in it (if the same number was added 5 times).

You should use a list instead:

```
import random
output = [] 

for x in range(5):
    integer = random.randint(1,10)
    output += [integer] 

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to generate `n` random unique numbers is to use `random.sample`:

```
>>> import random
>>> set(random.sample(range(1, 11), 5))
set([8, 9, 5, 6, 10])
```

Note that you should use `range(1, 11)` if you also want to include the number `10`.

Comment: this is a nice answer! I think if he is not conditioned to use `random.randint`, this is probably the best approach.

Answer (score -1):

Python sets will not show duplication. A simple way to fix your script is to use a list instead of a set. One thing to note however, is if you are going to want to use all the numbers together like `12345`, this won't do the trick. The following script will return a list as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

```
list1 = [] # Make an empty list

for x in range(5): 
    # randomly choose a number from 1 - 10 and append it to our list 5 times
    integer = random.randint(1,10)
    list1.append(integer)

print(list1) # print the list
```

Comment: How is this different than @NickA's answer?

Comment: NickA uses += as a way to add the number. I just used append. They do the exact same thing, I just also added comments to mine.